# SelectList with multiple values using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to build a select list with to values like this:

```
<ul id="sch-brand-dropdown">
    <li data-id="1" data-id2="11">text1</li>
    <li data-id="2" data-id2="12">text2</li>
    <li data-id="3" data-id2="13">text3</li>
</ul>
```

For one value I use the following method:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DropDownList()
{
    var brandServices = new BrandService();

    var brandsDTO = brandServices.GetAll().OrderBy(b => b.Name);

    var brandsList = brandsDTO.Select(brand =>
        new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = brand.Id.ToString(),
            Text = brand.Name
        });

    return brandsList;
}
```

Based on the Brand Model:

```
[Table("Brands")]
public class Brand
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

That I present in the view like this:

```
<ul id="sch-brand-dropdown">
    @foreach (var brand in Model.BrandList)
    {
        <li data-id="@brand.Value">@brand.Text</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Hi, the question is how can I build a select list with 2 values and 1 text

Comment: Dont use `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (thats for use by the `@Html.DropDownListFor()` method) Just create your own class with 3 properties for `ID1`, `ID2` and `Text`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi, thanks! can you just give me a simple example?

Comment: @Patrick, The answers by Mikhail Neofitov and Júlio Murta should be helpful

Comment: @StephenMuecke, yes I have received them now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe changing the return type of DropDownlist method:

```
public static IEnumerable<MultValoredItem> DropDownList()
{
    var brandServices = new BrandService();

    var brandsDTO = brandServices.GetAll().OrderBy(b => b.Name);

    var brandsList = brandsDTO.Select(brand =>
    new MultValoredItem
    {
        Value1 = brand.Id.ToString(),
        Value2 =  //Another value here
        Text = brand.Name
    });

    return brandsList;
}

public class MultValoredItem
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

<ul id="sch-brand-dropdown">
  @foreach (var brand in Model.BrandList)
  {
    <li data-id1="@brand.Value1" data-id2="@brand.Value2">@brand.Text</li>
  }
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! Can I ask you please to put in your example the way I can apply it in the View?

Comment: Thanks again Júlio, I have set your answer as correct because it was the fastest and most complete one :)

Answer (score 3):

Modify your model like

```
[Table("Brands")]
public class Brand
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

and use

```
<ul id="sch-brand-dropdown">
    @foreach (var brand in Model.BrandList)
    {
        <li data-id="@brand.Value1" data-id2="@brand.Value2">@brand.Text</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Mikhail! Thanks, don't get me wrong, I have set Júlio's answer as correct because it was the fastest and most complete one.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps it is not the best option but you can use either a repeater. Or instead use the literal directly with HTML code.

class :

```
public class Brand
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdCATEGORY { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

repeater :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater" runat="server" >
  <ItemTemplate>
    <li data-id="<%# Eval("id")  %>" data-id2="<%# Eval("idCATEGORY")  %>"><%# Eval("text")  %></li>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

use repeater in page_load:

```
 Repeater.DataSource = data_Brand;
 Repeater.DataBind();
```

Or literal -> then in c# create full string of `<ul><li>` by for? foreach? while?  and sen to literal inside page.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help but I prefer Júlio's answer becaus it's MVC based and more close to my code.